# Android : convert actual date and time to millis and other timezone

Tags: android, time, timezone

I must convert the actual date and time to millis and into other timezone GMT+3 (my timezone is GMT-2). I use this code but it return me hte time but into my timezone....why ?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-3"));
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
long timez = cal.getTime().getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SimpleDateFormat. Calendar always uses default configured timezone on your machine. Here is [example](http://www.javablogging.com/java-simpledateformat-examples/) on how to achieve this functionality with SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new Date();
  DateFormat firstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
  DateFormat secondFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
  TimeZone firstTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone(args[0]);
  TimeZone secondTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone(args[1]);
  firstFormat.setTimeZone(firstTime);
  secondFormat.setTimeZone(secondTime);
  System.out.println("-->"+args[0]+": " + firstFormat.format(date));
  System.out.println("-->"+args[1]+": " + secondFormat.format(date));
  }
```

where arg[0] and arg[1](http://www.roseindia.net/java/javadate/converting-time-time-zone.shtml) are the two time zone.
Refer this [LINK](http://www.roseindia.net/java/javadate/converting-time-time-zone.shtml)

Answer (score -1):

The getTime() method return the same time. it has no relation with the timezone.